# angular js import csv or json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.importer']);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
  enableGridMenu: true,
  data: 'data',
  importerDataAddCallback: function ( grid, newObjects ) {
  $scope.data = $scope.data.concat( newObjects );
  },
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ 
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
 };
 }]);
```

**Suppoese this is the json file**

```
[{
  "Name":"John Smith",
  "Gender":"male",
  "Company":"TestIcon"
 },
 {
  "Name":"Jane Doe",
  "Gender":"female",
  "Company":"FastTruck"
 }]
```

**Now i wll get the the grid having columns Name, Gender and Company.**

**Now how will i dynamically change the Grid column names : Like I want FirstName instead of Name**

Guys Please help me in sorting this

Comment: Why you want to change the json?

Comment: There is a case in my application, where i have predefined template like My template headers are **FirstName, Gender,CompanyName,** now i just want to map this template to different names used by different users in their json.

Comment: If you don't know before-hand what column names your users will have, you will need to have a way for them to choose the mapping. Or if you can do a best-guess you could create a pre-defined mapping dictionary, like 'name', 'firstName', 'name1', etc., all map to your 'FirstName' column definition.

Comment: Yes I will give the user, a option to map their column to my columns of predefined template.  Now my problem is , after mapping how will i dynamically change the grid headers column.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the name of your json object is gridJson:

```
var newGrid = gridJson.map(function(object) {
  object.FirstName = object.Name;
  delete object.Name;
  return object;
}
```

[Array.map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)